# rawsql equivalent django queryset

Tags: python, mysql, django

I would like to write django queryset which is equivalent of below query with one hit in db. Right now I am using `manager.raw()` to execute.

With `annotate`, I can generate the inner query. But I can't use that in the filter condition (when I checked `queryset.query`, it looks like ex1).

```
select *
from table1
where (company_id, year) in (select company_id, max(year) year
                             from table1
                             where company_id=3
                             and total_employees is not null
                             group by company_id);
```

Ex1:

```
SELECT `table1`.`company_id`, `table1`.`total_employees`
FROM `table1`
WHERE `table1`.`id` = (SELECT U0.`company_id` AS Col1, MAX(U0.`year`) AS `year`
                       FROM `table1` U0
                       WHERE NOT (U0.`total_employees` IS NULL)
                       GROUP BY U0.`company_id`
                       ORDER BY NULL)
```

Model:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, validators=[validate_not_null])
    total_employees = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dummy_relation')
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default="research")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('company', 'year',)
```

I appreciate your response.

Comment: can you share your model please?

Comment: I edited the origin question to add the model. Sample I gave id = 3. But my intention to fetch latest year employee_total for all companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) and [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to achive it. Try like this:

```
newest = Table1.objects.filter(company=OuterRef('pk'), total_employees_isnull=False).order_by('-year')
companies = Company.objects.annotate(total_employees=Subquery(newest.values('total_employees')[:1])).annotate(max_year=Subquery(newest.values('year')[:1]))
# these queries will not execute until you call companies. So DB gets hit once
```

Show values:

```
# all values
companies.values('id', 'total_employees', 'max_year')

# company three values
company_three_values = companies.filter(id=3).values('id', 'total_employees', 'max_year')
```

Filter on Max Year:

```
companies_max = companies.filter(max_year__gte=2018)
```

FYI: `OuterRef` and `Subquery` is available in Django from version 1.11

Comment: This is perfect.!! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

if you have model name is `Table1`, try this.

```
Table1.objects.get(pk=Table1.objects.filter(company_id=3, total_employees_isnull=False).latest('year').first().id)
```

This maybe one hit in db.

But if `.first()` not match anything. Better like this:

```
filter_item = Table1.objects.filter(company_id=3, total_employees_isnull=False).latest('year').first()
if filter_item:
   return Table1.objects.get(pk=filter_item.id)
```